# How to write a string to a column in csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write into a string to csv file using csv modules.
The string is getting printed in the excel sheet as single characters in different rows and not in one field.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow("hello")
    writer.writerow("bye")
```

The output is like

```
 h     e     l      l     o         
 b     y     e
```

What I simply want is

hello

bye

Also how do I write in a different column? there is no writecolumn() for it like writerow()

Comment: You have to give a list as the argument to `.writerow()`.

Comment: it treats the argument passed to it as an _iterable_ so wrap your words in brackets to signify you want it as one column

Comment: writerow takes a sequence of elements, each written in its own column.

Comment: OK now I understand. I made a list of the strings and now they are properly displayed and also thanks for the column idea.

Comment: Try `writer.writerow(["hello"])`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answer,

If you want to do the same with csv.writerows() function:

```
rows = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "orange"]

with open('test.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([[row] for row in rows])
```

That should print all the rows, in 1 column per row.

Answer (score 1):

In order to output in two rows:

```
writer.writerow(["hello"])
writer.writerow(["bye"])
```

In order to output in two cols:

```
 writer.writerow(["hello","bye"])
```